# Excel vlookup get the highest value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

Here is the excel function:

```
start date =IF(A6 = 1, C3, VLOOKUP(A6 -1, $A$6:$D$13, 4, FALSE))
end date =C6+B6
```

I intend to get the latest end date value if there is multiple rows on previous sequences, for example as below:

On the yellow cell, it should get the 23/2/2019 instead of 18/2/2019.

[image]

Comment: Hi @AnilGoyal, yes desired formula should change to 23/2/2019 which get max of same value

Comment: Check the answer please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will serve your purpose.  **This is formula for first start-date value and drag it downwards.**

```
=IF(A6=1,$C$3,MAX(IF(A6-1=$A$6:$A$14,VLOOKUP(A6-1,$A$6:$D$14,3)+$B$6:$B$14)))
```

**NOTE** this is array formula so enter it with `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter` and check for `curly braces` around the formula.  The screenshot to check for all conditions

[image]

Check for seq 6, I added two values sorted differently now

Comment: thanks, works well. Just curious can array function be used inside like =if(a6=1,...{max(if(....))}) instead of most outer part {=if(....)} ?

Comment: Yes, both ways.  It depends on output where you are getting an array.  `Choose` function uses curly braces inside normal braces for example.

Answer (score 2):

Use `LOOKUP`:

```
=IF(A12=1,C9,LOOKUP(A12-1,$A$6:$A$13,$D$6:$D$13))
```

[image]

**Edit:**

to get latest date you can use `AGGREGATE` function:

```
=IF(A6 = 1; C3; AGGREGATE(14;4;($A$6:$A$13=A6 -1)*$D$6:$D$13;1))
```

[image]

Comment: This will return last of the two values and not max value always!  try it

Comment: @AnilGoyal Yes, you are probably right. I add an additional option.

Comment: Yes! Perfect. Thanks for sharing a tip. Upvoted+1, Can you please also clarify why you used argument (14- large) instead of (4-max)?

Comment: @AnilGoyal 4-max does not accept calculated arrays - only exact range.